# How to stop web apps from opening in youtube?

Tags: html, ipad, web-applications, youtube, mobile-safari

I am making a mobile web app for iPad. I got the code off googles website to add a youtube subscribe button:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCICWAtoGya9rQRPRSseDpjw" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

Whenever I open the web app -- before the app even loads and without a prompt -- it opens the YouTube app. Can anyone help me, please?

I made a new web app at http://mazes.ml/web-app with the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YouTube Button</title>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="YouTube Button">
</head>

<body>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCICWAtoGya9rQRPRSseDpjw" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on youtube's code, actually. The only way that Google can verify that the button is actually being intentionally pressed (as opposed to by a script on your site) is by authenticating the user themselves, and on many mobile browsers, it will automatically open an associated app when the user is directed to youtube from your site.

Comment: but it opens youtube if I didn't click on the button. It opens the youtube app on start up.

Comment: Are you putting the script tag in the page's head, or inside the body? The latter could potentially mess things up for you.

Comment: I put the script in the head and it still opens in youtube.